# How to mimic the orange outline on focus?

Tags: html, css, focus

I am creating a set of divs which the user can navigate through with tab, and I wanted to add the standard orange focus outline to the elements.

Does anyone know what I need to do to add it in? I know that it works off the outline property, but I'm not sure what color to set it as, or whether I'd be better off using a box shadow with a bit of blur to get the same effect.

Also, in case it's relevant, I'm using dojo and avoiding jquery - but hopefully this is a pure css solution :)

Comment: I dont knw what you are going to achieve, it would be helpfull if you put your code together in jsfiddle (if you have tried something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enbs/ZRhNd/), note that in order to accomplish this you will have to use `<div tabindex="0"></div>`.

Every browser renders the focus differently. In order to unify the entire experience on your website, I would suggest removing the browser outline with CSS and adding your own style.

As far as I know, only Chrome renders the orange outline, I've tried to match the color as best as I could, but you can always experiment on your own.

Comment: @Emma Something else you might want to take note of, there's a `border-radius: 2px;` in the CSS in order to achieve the slightly rounded design of the Chrome outline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css :focus Pseudo selector

```
:focus {
    declaration block
}
```

Although the `div` attribute does not accept input, so it cannot have `:focus` normally. So you would have to set the div's to have a `tabindex` attribute